# Web App: Gathering unknown amount of data from user an unknown number of times

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**My Problem** I am writing an app for internal use at my pharmacy.  I am gathering some usage data from multiple pharmacy systems to help manage inventory.  95% of the records I can automatically parse how many tablets are used every day, but there are some that require user input.  This input consists of 3 fields (date, time, number of tabs) for an unknown number of records.  For example, twice a day would have 6 records for 3 days, whereas 3 times a day would have 9.

**My Current Solution** The user selects the records to process and starts the procedure.  Any records that can be automatically processed are taken care of.  Any records requiring user input are stuck in a table.  Upon refresh of the page, an Ajax request checks the table for any records.  If a record is present, a modal is shown to the user to allow their input.  The input form has a "new record" button that shows another round of the 3 fields, then the data is POSTed to a php script.  The script processes the data and removes the affected record.  If multiple records, the ajax script pops another modal.  This continues until the table is empty.

**Help** There has to be a more elegant solution out there.  I've look at several CRUD grids, but most seem to be about showing and editing data, not about general data entry.

**Sorry** for the wall of text.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What's the bottleneck?

Comment: The number of steps required is frustrating to the user.  Too many page reloads.  I would love something like datagridview from .NET allowing me to generate 1 grid for each record and let the user enter all on one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this

http://www.labs.mimmin.com/inlineedit/

http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/tableEditor/example_new.php

I found it on google by using 'jquery inline editable table'

I know Yii has a nice admin interface specifically fast input, but I sense you wrote the code yourself, transferring to Yii might be a bigger challenge that solving this in a nice way.

good luck

Comment: That's the nicest looking table I've seen in my searching, but it doesn't appear to handle what I'm trying to accomplish.  I start with zero data, and the user enters everything.

Comment: I think I can take some of the concepts used in the dev.iceburg.net link to make this work.  They fired a database write every time a user adds a row.  If I do that, then I can combine multiple tables on one page, solving my problem.  Thanks.